# What is the sample space in this case?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A bag has $3$ items labelled $A, B, C$ .

What is the sample space of choosing $2$ items from this bag without replacement, and with replacement?

I got $S_1 = \{AB, BC, AC, BA, CB, CA\} $ and $S_2 = \{AB, BC, AC\}$. Is it correct?

Comment: With replacement you could also get $AA,BB,CC$.  And if order matters for the non-replacement case, why do you ignore it in the replacement case?

Comment: When does order matter?

Comment: When the problem under discussion requires it.  As you choose one, and then choose another, there is a natural way to order the pair.

Comment: My professor didn't specify it tho.

Comment: Then I would assume it mattered.  You can always declare that event $AB$ is the same as event $BA$ after the fact.  Keeping information is better than discarding it.

Comment: So S1 = {AB, BC, AC, BA, CB, CA} and S2 = {AB, BC, AC, BA, CB, CA, AA, BB, CC}, am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would use.

Comment: @YolandaHui  It might be good to use order for the second case as well, so that you get AA,AB,AC,BA,BB,BC, CA,CB, and CC.  The advantage of doing this is that you can now note that there is only one way to get two $A$'s (namely, through $AA$), but there are two ways to get one $A$ and one $B$: (namely, through $AB$ and $BA$). So, you are twice as likely to get one $A$ and one $B$ as a result of picking two items (with replacement) than to get two $A$'s.